# Jetta turns off immediately after starting

Tags: electrical, vw, starting, fuse

So I parked my Jetta ('06 2.5) 2 nights ago, when I went to start it yesterday morning, the starter seems to work fine- turns over, then instead of idling down, it turns off. Must have tried it 5 times yesterday and 2-3 times today, always the same thing.

Since the instrument panel isn't lighting up, I figured it was a fuse. I checked 2 fuse boxes looking for a blown fuse, but none look bad. Because of the IP I'm still quite certain this is electrical. Any recommendations before I call the garage to come check it out?

Comment: Removed/reattached battery and now it runs fine. Airbag warning light is on though. Thoughts on that?

Answer (score 2):

Could be a short, but most likely was a bad connection on the battery causing a short, thus the car turned itself off to prevent any damages, now that everything works, check the fuses again to see about the airbag light.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider is that the immobilizer is in the instrument cluster in many VW products. If you've lost power to the cluster, the immobilizer may be kicking in. This should happen about 30 seconds after starting.

The airbag light will be accompanied by codes, read them to see what's up.